# What is the final price if the bid price exceeds the ask price in an order driven market?

Tags: stocks, limit-order, bid-ask

Let's assume a very simplified situation. There is only one seller asking for 10$ and there is only one buyer bidding 20$. At what price would the transaction go?

Some answers say it won't, because the ask price has to match the bid price. ([Does a market maker sell (buy) at a bid or ask price?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15572/does-a-market-maker-sell-buy-at-a-bid-or-ask-price)) Other answers say, that the time ordering is important. ([Bid-Ask at market open, which comes first?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/bid-ask-at-market-open-which-comes-first)) Which answer is correct? What is the final price in the presented situation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **earliest** order is the price.

If the seller submits a Limit Order to Sell at $10 at 9:30 AM, it will enter the order book and $10 will be shown to the world as **Best Ask**.

Then if the buyer submits a Limit Order to Buy at $20 at 9:31 AM, it becomes a **Marketable** Limit Order because $20 is better than the Best Ask of $10.

The trade will be executed at $10, **not** somewhere between $10 and $20.

That limit order to buy at $20 will never be shown in the order book, nor will the $20 be shown as best bid.

A trade happens when:

- **Incoming** Buy Order has limit price equal to or above National Best Offer; or
- **Incoming** Sell Order has limit price equal to or below National Best Bid.

For examples of rules, please see
http://nysearcarules.nyse.com/pcx/pcxe/pcxe-rules/chp_1_1/chp_1_1_8/chp_1_1_8_3/chp_1_1_8_3_11/default.asp