# What does a stock's quoted value represent?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, price, yahoo-finance

According to Yahoo Finance, a single stock in Alphabet Inc. is worth 898.7 USD as of this writing.

**Question:** What does the price of $898.7 reflect?
I can imagine the price is one of the following options:

1. Highest bidding price
2. Lowest asking price
3. Price for the latest transaction

Comment: the question as asked, answered, and accepted doesn't really match the title.

Comment: Feel free to suggest a different title.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The quote price is simply the last price at which a trade completed.

Comment: So what prohibits a company from purchasing its own stock a 2x the price to artificially bump quote price?

Comment: @Phil: The law.

Comment: @Phil I think Lighntess is overcomplicating it. The company can buy its own stock at 2x the value, but other sellers will still be selling it at the regular price. If you are a random buyer, who are you going to go with? The seller selling at the normal rate or the seller selling at 2x rate?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually this sorta kinda happens already, although not from the company itself - often another company will offer to buy the company's stock at a premium to its current trading price.  Usually the trading price will quickly rise to close to the offer price.

Comment: @Michael that's how hostile takeovers happen/begin yeah? Company Y says they'll buy company X's stock at a premium in an effort to gain a ton of shares?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I believe you mean "if you are a random seller who are you going to sell to? The buyer asking the normal rate or the buyer asking 2x rate?"

Comment: @user20574 No, I mean if you are a random buying who (as in which seller) are you going to go with.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg But there is no seller offering 2x the market value. The question was about if the company is offering to *buy* their stock for 2x the market value.

Comment: @Phil: Generally, a lack of cash. A company with $100 million in outstanding stocks usually doesn't have $200 million available.

Comment: It seems that from the way the market rules are executed, it won't get bought at the 2x price. See here: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/52265/36734

Comment: @Phil Why would they waste their money doing that? An increase in the quoted stock price has no benefit to the company. (An increase in the price at which you can _actually sell_ the stock benefits it when issuing new stock, or when employees cash in share options, but artificially boosting the quoted price in the way you suggest will have no effect on the price you can actually get for the stock.)

Comment: @phil the law as Lightness stated. Any company that is trading its own stock have to disclose an investment plan with some antecedence. Otherwise it is inside trading. https://www.sidley.com/-/media/files/publications/2013/11/trading-by-corporate-directors-and-their-affilia__/files/view-article/fileattachment/final-best-law-firms-2014-article-2-pages--11-05__.pdf

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are talking about inside trading legislation, right? The company can trade its own stock at whatever price they want, but they have to disclose an investment plan ahead of time. https://www.sidley.com/-/media/files/publications/2013/11/trading-by-corporate-directors-and-their-affilia__/files/view-article/fileattachment/final-best-law-firms-2014-article-2-pages--11-05__.pdf

Comment: @Phil Even if the company does this, it will just be an outlier in the company's stock price chart. Other sales that day will be at a price that regular investors are willing to pay. And the company will lose lots of cash, since they won't be able to sell the shares for anything close to what they paid for them.

Comment: @Phil Stock prices are typically only published from markets that have trading rules. And one typical rule is that you can't buy a stock for more than the lowest price for which it is on offer. Other than to manipulate the market or launder money, why would you want to? And why should the market let you do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Price for the latest transaction.** If the stock is selling for  $898.7 means that the stock is **currently trading for  $898.7**, and it will be your **ask price** of stock if you purchase currently.

Comment: I am not sure your last comment, "... it will be your ask price of stock if you purchase currently" is necessarily correct. It is possible that the latest transaction occurred at 898.7, but the current lowest ask price might now be 900 [because all shareholders offering 898.7 to sell their shares have been bought out at that price, and no other current offers exist until 900]. This is why it is important to note *all of* the ask price, bid price, and latest transaction price.

Comment: Why bold when 1/3 of the words in your answer are bold?

Comment: @quid: It's very bold of him

Answer (score 0):

Stock price is set to the price with the highest transaction volume at any given time.

```
price x no of stocks traded
```

The stock price you cited was only valid in the last transaction on a specific stock exchange. As such it is more of an "historic" value. Next trade will be done with the next biggest volume. Depending on the incoming bids and asks this could be higher or lower, but you can assume it will not be too far off if there is no crash underway.

Simple example stock exchange:

```
Buyer A wants 20 for max   $400
Buyer B wants 10 for max   $900
Buyer C wants  2 for max $1,000

Seller A offers  5 for min $700
Seller B offers  5 for min $900
Seller C offers 30 for min $950

Price will be $900 at which 10 stocks can be traded = trade volume $9,000
If it was $899 only 5 could be traded = $4,495
If it was $901 only 2 could be traded = $1,802
```